# Websphere install features server generate webservices

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, websphere-7

I work with Eclipse and Websphere. I wrote a Java class and I want to create a webservice using  File->New->Web services  and this bean.

Also, I want to create a client.

The execution environment server is JAX-WS de IBM WebSphere in the service and in the client.

In the webservice wizard I select Execute service, Test Client and Monitoring Service

When I click finish creation web service wizard I get the error

```
"It is necessary to install tools destination server to generate code webservices"
```

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHR6W/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/jaxws/twsbeanjaxws.htm

Comment: In a "dynamic web project", I tried this in WebSphere Developer Tools against WebSphere Liberty.  I didn't see "Execute service, Test Client and Monitoring Service".  Perhaps  what you're seeing is specific to some particular version of Eclipse tooling and/or WebSphere. Could you elaborate on what you're using?

Comment: I use IBM Rational® Application Developer for WebSphere® Software 9.1. I created a bean. In this bean right click and WebServices-> create webservices. I see a screen with some parts. In the first I click configuration server and I chose JAX-WS of webSphere